# Scheme is removed from url in safari

Tags: safari, url

If I call a website with an unknown "tld" like `.loc`, then safari is removing the scheme (in this case `http://`). This means that Safari will do a quick search, if I want to change something in the url.

Example:
I call a website `http://foo-project.loc/bar/baz`. The website is getting opened.
If I want to change `baz` to `boo`, then Safari opens a Google quick search.
How can I prevent Safari from removing the scheme from the url, because I actually like it to quick search in the url bar.

Comment: Do you have a real example that someone can try?

Comment: For me this is a real example. I use devilbox to develop web-apps. You may probably setup a custom hostname in your /etc/hosts file to reproduce this.